# Will returning nil in init cause a memory leak?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting

Will returning `nil` under ARC in `init` lead to memory leak, when `[super init]` was already called, but then returned nil? Is this a legit usage?

```
- (id)init {
   self = [super init];
   if (self) {

       ...
       return nil;
       ...

   }
   return self;
}
```

Comment: Why should you return nil inside your if condition when self has already been initialized.

Comment: No.  You are releasing a reference so it should operate just like releasing a reference anywhere else in code.

Comment: @iosDev82: That's quite common if your own initialisation fails.

Comment: @gnasher729 Yeah I reckon that makes sense as well. It's just that it threw me off a bit, since I never return anything inside the if. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all: For Qs referring to ARC never read Apple's documentation, but clang's.

Apple's documentation simply conceals (concealed?) the execution of `-init` and have wrong examples like that:

```
id ref = [[Class alloc] init]
```

You will find there a statement like "`+alloc` transfers ownership". This is at least misleading, because the return value auf `-init` and *not* the return value of `+alloc` is stored.

clang's documentation is better and more precise by far. Basically they say, that `+alloc` is an ownership transfer *and* that `-init` is ownership consuming and  ownership transferring.

http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#semantics-of-init

> Methods in the init family implicitly consume their self parameter and return a retained object.

So let's have a look to the usual code:

```
id ref = [Class alloc]; 
// ref is strong: RC is +1;
id ref = [ref init];    
  // Three things happen her:
  // 1. -init is executed
  // 2. The new value is stored
  // 3. The old value of ref is lost

  // 1. -init is executed
  // self is (silently) passed to the receiver
  - (id)init           
  {
    // Since self is strong (+1), RC is +2 now
    // Since -init is ownership consuming (-1), RC is +1 now
    …
    return self;
    // Since -init is ownership transferring (+1), RC is +2 now
  }

  // 2. The new value is stored
  // The value comes from an ownership transfer method, so the assignment to strong ref is neutral (0), RC is still +2

  // 3. The old value is lost (-1), RC is +1
```

The result is that the object has an RC of +1 and you have one strong reference to it in that code area. Everything is fine. (Of course there is a high potential for optimization, because in most cases neither `self` nor `ref` is changed, but let's keep on the regular track.)

Let's change `self` inside `-init`:

```
id ref = [Class alloc]; // Ownership transfer. RC is +1;
id ref = [ref init];    
  // Three things happen her:
  // 1. -init is executed
  // 2. The new value is stored
  // 3. The old value of ref is lost

  // 1. -init is executed
  //     self is (silently) passed to the receiver
  - (id)init           
  {
    // Since self is strong (+1), RC is +2 now
    // Since -init is ownership consuming (-1), RC is +1 now

    // Let's return nil as in your example
    return nil;
    // Because nil is returned, virtually the RC of nil is increased. self's RC == +1 is unchanged.
  }

  // 2. The new value is stored
  // The new value is nil.
  // However the value comes from an ownership transfer method, so the assignment to strong ref is neutral (0), RC is still +1

  // 3. The old value is lost (your old ref and the self while executing -init) (-1), RC is 0
  // The old object is dealloced, if you do not have another ref to it. Nothing leaks.
```

Answer (score 0):

I just checked that in the Instruments - no memory leaks

Comment: and is this a legit usage? or might break in future?

Comment: @PeterLapisu it's what you are supposed to do.  Apple document it.

Comment: @PeterLapisu under ARC it's OK as described in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html)